# Need to fix this proof: Open linear subspace is equal to its normed superspace.

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-verification, normed-spaces

Let $X$ be a normed linear space and let $V\subset X$ be a linear subspace. Prove that if $V$ is open, then $X=V$.

---

We need to prove that $X\subset V$. Let there be a sequence $x_n\in X$ such that $x_n\to x$ with $x\in V$. There exists $N\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that for all $n\geq N$ $x_n\in V$. Hence there is an open ball $B(x_n;\epsilon)\subset V$ with $\epsilon >0$, around $x_n$.

Here is where I need help. Intuitively I know that 
$$x_n\in B(x_n;\epsilon) \implies x_{n-1}\in B(x_n;\epsilon)$$

Can I just make $x_n$ arbitrarily close to each other? Is there a more rigorous approach to tackle this last part? Maybe using the fact that $V$ is closed under addition and scalar multiplication of vectors?

Comment: It's easier.  If $V$ is open, it contains a ball around $0$.  Hence ...

Comment: @fredgoodman Hence for any given $x\in X$ the ball around zero $B(0,\epsilon)$ contains $y=\lambda x$ such that $\|\lambda x\|<\epsilon$ and hence it also contains $x$. Is that the reasoning?

Comment: Yes, although you didn't express it well.  What is "it" in "it also contains $x$".

Comment: @fredgoodman $V$ because it is a linear space and hence closed under scalar multiplication. Thus since $\lambda x\in B\subset V$ then $x\in V$

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: @fredgoodman Thank you very much for the help!